# Problems starting Sonatype Nexus 2.11.3

Tags: startup, nexus

When attempting to start Nexus 2.11.3 i.e. ./bin/nexus console it attempts 5 times and fails.  The error log set at debug level output is not intuitive as to where to even start with trouble-shooting.  Perhaps others are familiar with some of the output.  BTW. I run JAVA JDK 1.7u1.

```
Command(0) : java
Command(1) : -XX:MaxPerSize=192m
Command(2) : -Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp
Command(3) : -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Command(4) : -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol=plain ssl
Command(5) : -Xms256m
Command(6) : -Xmx768m
Command(7) : -Djava.library.path=bin/jsw/lib
Command(8) : classpath
Command(9) : <Large list of jar files>
Command(10) : -Dwrapper.key=<key>
Command(11) : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command(12) : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command(13) : -Dwrapper.port.max=5939
Command(14) : -Dwrapper.debug=true
Command(15) : -Dwrapper.pid=5939
Command(16) : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command(17) : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command(18) : -Dwrapper.timeout=10
Command(19) : -Dwrapper.jvmid=5
Command(20) : org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jw..JswLauncher
Command(21) : ./conf/jetty.xml
Command(22) : ./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml
Launching JVM
Signal trapped: Details:
  signal number 17  (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
JVM exited while loading the application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Java 7 or even better Java 8. Update 1 of Java 7 had numerous issues and among other things does not work with Nexus.

Also note that only Oracle JVM is officially supported.

Btw here are the full Nexus sytem requirements in detail:

http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/try-compare-buy/nexus-requirements

Comment: I tried 1.7.0.65 with same result.  Is there any way that I can get more log details to clue me in?

Comment: What JVM are you using? Only Oracle JDK is officially supported..  also can you show the full log e.g. in a gist or somewhere.

Comment: I was using OpenJDK, but now that I've switched to Oracle it's working.  Thanks